# Como usar vetores/arrays em Java?

Tags: java, android, array

Olá, sou bem leigo em Java e preciso usar uma variável armazenando várias outras. Como posso fazer isso? Tenho o seguinte:

```
LatLng ponto1 = new LatLng(-19.924312,-43.931762);
LatLng ponto2 = new LatLng(-18.851388,-41.946910);
```

Eu estou acostumado com C, onde eu poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
LatLng pontos[2];
LatLng pontos[1] = new LatLng(-19.924312,-43.931762);
LatLng pontos[2] = new LatLng(-18.851388,-41.946910);
```

Mas quando tento isso no Android Studio, ele me retorna erros de sintaxe... Como seria a maneira correta de fazer?

Obs.: Preciso fazer isso para comparar vários "pontos" dentro de um "for", acho que essa é a melhor maneira...

**--- EDIT ---**

Ele me retorna erros do tipo:

- Unkown class: pontos
- Missing method body, or declare abstract

**--EDIT2-- (código, como o Maniero pediu)**

```
public class Mapa extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

LatLng ponto1 = new LatLng(-19.924312,-43.931762);
LatLng ponto2 = new LatLng(-18.851388,-41.946910);

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Mapa.this,     android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Mapa.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Mapa.this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }else{
        if(!mMap.isMyLocationEnabled())
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (myLocation == null) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }

        if(myLocation!=null){
            LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 14), 1500, null);
            double distancia = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(ponto1, userLocation);
            double valorLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            double valorLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

            /*String stringLongitude = Double.toString(valorLongitude);
            String stringLatitude = Double.toString(valorLatitude);*/
            String stringDistancia = Double.toString(distancia);

            TextView textLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLatitude);
            textLatitude.setText(stringDistancia);
            /*TextView textLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLongitude);
            textLongitude.setText(stringLongitude);*/
        }
    }
}
```

Eu estou usando a função 'SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween' para calcular a distancia do ponto1 com a posição do usuário. Isso funciona normalmente... Agora eu precisava de um 'for' para calcular a distancia de cada ponto que eu listar acima em relação a posição do usuário e depois me retornar a menor distância... Para isso, eu acho que precisaria colocar todos os pontos em uma única array e testar elemento por elemento da array, mas não sei como declarar a array lá em cima...

Comment: E onde está o código? Você pode [edit] a pergunta e colocá-lo pra gente analisar

Comment: Código adicionado (:

Comment: Só com isso não dá para saber, ou talvez o erro é só ter isso :)

Comment: Basicamente só tem isso na minha classe do mapa, eu só deixei de listar os imports e o package hehe

Comment: Não entendi sua comparação com a linguagem C...

Comment: É que na linguagem C, eu posso declarar uma array, por exemplo, do tipo int com 11 elementos (começa a contar do 0)... Ficaria algo como:

    int array[10];

E, logo após, eu poderia acessar o elemento de posição 5 usando:

array[5];

Tentei fazer algo parecido em Java para exemplificar

Answer (score 4):

Em java, aprenda que a linguagem base é isso, só a base, um dos grandes fortes do Java é suas bibliotecas built-in que fazem 1001 coisas, e já vem todas pre-made no JDK.

Uma Array, da maneira que você está acostumado em C seria:

```
Object[] array = new Object[10];
```

isso cria uma array vazia do tipo `Object` de 10 indices, vazia.
Mas nas versões mais novas do java temos o 'atalho':

```
String[] array = {"um elemento", "outro elemento"}
```

Que inicializa uma array com tamanho 2 e já com os dois elementos dentro, o padrão pode se aplicar a qualquer outro tipo de variável. Numeros, objetos:

```
{new LatLang(10.22, -2.44),new LatLang(1.22, -4.66)}
```

etc...
Mas no java 8 é muito mais comum a versão mais "moderna" de conjuntos java Listas, Mapas, Sets, ETC

O equivalente a arrays nessa nossa livraria de conjuntos seria `ArrayList`, a diferença é que conjuntos são objetos, tem tamanho dinâmicos e suportam varias operações built-in: ordenar, tirar item especifico, procurar, etc. Elas são parte da JDK e você pode usar:

```
ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList(); 
// E para adicionar items:
lista.add(new Object());
// Voce pode ate especificar o indice
lista.add(3, new Object());
// Mas cuidado, as listas se por mais que listas se expandam sozinhas para 
// acomodar novos indices elas tem índice. o padrão inicial é 10
// voce nao pode acabar de criar uma lista e:
lista.add(10000, new Object());
```

Comment: Hm... Entendido! Mas então, qual seria mais apropriado pro que eu preciso fazer? Usar esse tipo de arrays, ou listas como citado pelo amigo J. Guilherme? E quais as principais diferenças? Se não me engano, no caso da lista, quando retirado um elemento, o próximo elemento toma a posição dele, algo assim?

Comment: Certo, funcionará perfeitamente com o que preciso! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Feliz em ajudar. Para acessar os built-ins que menceonei é lista.metodo()

Comment: Top! me economizou um bom tempo, estava quebrando a cabeça com Arrays de tamanho dinâmico em Java, estou muito acostumado com os Arrays dinâmicos da linguagem PHP, usei seu exemplo no formato String `private ArrayList<String> mTrainingPath = new ArrayList();`, funcionou perfeitamente... Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Cria uma lista:

```
List<LatLng> pontos = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
pontos.add(new LatLng(-19.924312,-43.931762));
pontos.add(new LatLng(-18.851388,-41.946910));
```

Depois recupere por `pontos.get(0)`, por exemplo.

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo que eu preciso, porém quando eu adiciono as 3 linhas que você disse, o Android Studio sublinha de vermelho o trecho 'new List<LatLng>();' e me retorna a mensagem 'List' is abstract; cannot be instantied... O que pode ser?

Comment: Em java, List é interface.. eu não sabia.. Uma implementação concreta de List é ArrayList.. veja minha edição

Comment: Ah, sim... Entendi... Perfeito, então! Deu certo aqui... Agradeço muito!